# Dell Inspiron 1525 - internal hard drive not found

Tags: dell-inspiron

I have a dell 1525 laptop and it won't boot up.  I keep getting the message internal hard drive not found.  I called Dell and they are send me a new hard drive, but I need the info on this hard drive.  How can I retrieve it?

Comment: What kind of "info" do you need? Make/model? because we couldn't possibly tell you that without at least a model number. Or are you asking how to put your old stuff on the new hard drive? Because if they had to send you a new one it is more than likely dead which is going to make retrieving data difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Most dells have this.  While trying to boot up, tap F12.  You should be brought to a menu.  Using your keyboard select diagnostics.  let it run, and most likely it will find a harddrive error.  If you don't have any external encloser you can put the harddrve in, then you will want to download a Linux boot cd and try to copy the files you need to a flashdrive or if they are small email them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the drive is still working, you could try taking the drive out and putting it in a drive enclosure, then get the data from that.  Otherwise, you may have to try a data recovery service.  [Lowcostrecovery](http://lowcostrecovery.com/) looks fairly cheap as data recovery services go, but shop around, because I don't have any experience with data recovery companies.